# How to convert timestamp to date format in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to convert timestamp to date format which is 'dd/MM/YYYY' but I end up with date format in the picture. I also use syncfusion spreadsheet.

[image: Timestamp]

export-electronic.component.ts

```
updatedata(){
        this.dataApi.getElectronicById(this.id).subscribe(res => {
          this.electronicObj = res;
          console.log(this.electronicObj);
          this.spreadsheetObj.updateCell({ value: 
          this.electronicObj.mantainence_history},"O3");
          this.spreadsheetObj.updateCell({ value: 
          this.electronicObj.cost_status},"P3");
          this.spreadsheetObj.updateCell({ value: this.electronicObj.warranty_date.toDate()+this.electronicObj.expire_date.toDate()},"Q3");}
```

export-electronic.component.html

```
<ejs-spreadsheet #spreadsheet  (created)="created()" (openComplete)="updatedata()" openUrl='https://ej2services.syncfusion.com/production/web-services/api/spreadsheet/open' allowOpen='true' (beforeSave)='beforeSave($event)' saveUrl='https://ej2services.syncfusion.com/production/web-services/api/spreadsheet/save'  allowSave='true'> 
</ejs-spreadsheet>
```

In the excel cell. I want the answer around like this. Example 29/11/2022 - 01/12/2022
Thank you for the advice

**** The Answer *****

```
updatedata(){
    this.dataApi.getElectronicById(this.id).subscribe(res => {
        this.electronicObj = res;
        console.log(this.electronicObj);
        const q3Value = (new Date(this.electronicObj.warranty_date.toDate()).toLocaleDateString('en-GB')) + ' - ' + (new Date(this.electronicObj.expire_date.toDate()).toLocaleDateString('en-GB'));
        this.spreadsheetObj.updateCell({ value: 
        this.electronicObj.mantainence_history},"O3");
        this.spreadsheetObj.updateCell({ value: 
        this.electronicObj.cost_status},"P3");
        this.spreadsheetObj.updateCell({ value: q3Value},"Q3");
    });
}
```

[image: Answer]

Comment: You should use the [`DatePipe`](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe)

Comment: is there the way to convert timestamp in Ts file ? because Datepipe is format for html. Ty for the advice

Comment: https://angular.io/api/common/formatDate

Comment: What is your toDate() function doing? Is it from any library like momentjs?

Comment: toDate() in my TS , is for converting timestramp to date but it's not in the date format that I want. :(

Comment: Could you update your question and include the toDate() function also? Lets see what it is doing.

Comment: You should try searching for this information before asking here. It's in the top 3 search  results.

Comment: toDate() is not actually function in Ts . I just put in the back of warranty_date because I want it in date not timestamp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert your date string (or timestamp) to a JS date object and format it to your liking. Below is an example of formatting a date to "dd/mm/yyyy" format:

```
new Date('Mon Nov 9 13:29:40 2012').toLocaleDateString('en-GB');
```

Here locale 'en-GB' ensures that you get dd/mm/yyyy always.

So, you can update your code like this:

```
updatedata(){
    this.dataApi.getElectronicById(this.id).subscribe(res => {
        this.electronicObj = res;
        console.log(this.electronicObj);
        const q3Value = (new Date(this.electronicObj.warranty_date).toLocaleDateString('en-GB')) + ' - ' + (new Date(this.electronicObj.expire_date).toLocaleDateString('en-GB'));
        this.spreadsheetObj.updateCell({ value: 
        this.electronicObj.mantainence_history},"O3");
        this.spreadsheetObj.updateCell({ value: 
        this.electronicObj.cost_status},"P3");
        this.spreadsheetObj.updateCell({ value: q3Value},"Q3");
    });
}
```

Here, you are creating the formatted date range before pushing into the spreadsheet. Look for the variable **q3Value**.

Comment: I try it but it shows Invalid Date - Invalid Date. but ty for the example.

Comment: I put .toDate() at the end of each Obj and it works out. I did update my post. thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try one of them

1. Pipe

```
getFormatedDate(date: Date, format: string) {
    const datePipe = new DatePipe('en-US'); // culture of your date
    return datePipe.transform(date, format);
}
```

2. moment.js

```
    let parsedDate = moment(dateStr,"MM-DD-YYYY");
    let outputDate = parsedDate.format("DD-MM-YYYY");
```

3. Simple Split

```
const str = '10-23-2022';

const [month, day, year] = str.split('-');

console.log(month); // ️ "10"
console.log(day); // ️ "23"
console.log(year); // ️ "2022"

const date = new Date(+year, +month - 1, +day);

console.log(date);
```

Comment: Since Angular 9 you can use directly [formatDate](https://angular.io/api/common/formatDate): `return formatDate(date,'en-US')` instead of create a new DatePipe